# Case creation in Lightning - Send notification email to contact option not sending email when Process updates record

Tags: lightning, email, process-builder, case

Asking here to see if anyone knows about this interaction, and hoping to avoid initiating another month or more of frustration trying to work through Salesforce's Customer Support.

The situation is as follows:

1. A user is creating a new Case through the Lightning UI
2. User is providing a Contact for the case, and is checking the "Send notification email to contact" box
3. "Save" button is clicked, starting the record insertion
4. A Process is being run, which has an immediate action that updates the Case record being inserted
5. The notification email *does not get sent to the contact*

*This is only an issue when the case is created from the Lightning UI*. When testing the same scenario, but from the Classic UI, the notification email is sent.

My org is very heavily customized, and the Case object has Process(es) (built using Process Builder), Workflow rules, and a trigger. I don't think those details are relevant though, because I was able to reproduce this in my personal developer edition org (which is still pretty vanilla) by simply creating a process that updates the newly inserted Case record.

What is it about Lightning that causes this failure? Is there a workaround (other than not using Lightning)?

#### +edit: The following critical update(s) have been applied to the org we're testing this in, prior to our tests for this issue:

- Stop Automated Field Updates from Suppressing Email Notifications

Comment: Have you looked at testing in an org with the `Stop Automated Field Updates from Suppressing Email Notifications` critical update activated?

Comment: You can write a process (using PB) to notify the Contact? Why rely on that box?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Looks like that particular critical update has been applied in an org that we've tested on. Problem still exists.

Comment: I got the same result. I was able to replicate your issue in a trailhead org (just one PB that updates a field on case). I also tried with the `Evaluate Criteria Based on Original Record Values in Process Builder` critical update activated and the problem still exists. The checkbox to send the email works fine as soon as the PB is deactivated

Comment: @Maneesh Because it's standard functionality provided by Salesforce, and using standard functionality is preferred over custom solutions. The standard feature gets special treatment (i.e. it can appear in areas that would be hard/impossible to reproduce with customizations), and it's what my users are used to. Yes, the customization could be made, and users can be re-trained, but duplicating features isn't attractive as a business proposal. Still, thanks for your input. That was a question worth sorting out before reaching out to support.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Always good to know I'm not the crazy one (or just missing something simple like that critical update).

Comment: Sounds a bit like this known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YnJRQA0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, if you can put the record update into a scheduled action rather than an immediate action, then the email notification will be sent.

The minimum time delay for a scheduled action appears to be 1 hour.

Being able to create a scheduled action in Process Builder means that you need to:

- Have your process set to execute only on record creation, and/or...
- Have your criteria node set to only trigger "when specified changes are made to the record" (under the "advanced" accordion menu)

This does impose some restrictions that may make the workaround non-viable for some.

For my org though, having the email sent out is vital. An hour delay is less than ideal, but it beats needing someone to use data loader or anonymous apex every day.

Answer (score 3):

At Derek's suggestion I'll turn my comment into an answer:

The problem sound like the known issue  [Send Notification Email to Contact on Cases does not send email](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YnJRQA0). If I remember correctly this issue had been in review for quite some time, so requesting an update from support may unfortunately be in order.

There's also this known issue, which sounds similar, and may have the same underlying cause: ["Send Email Notification to Contact" failing to trigger email in lightning when flow is attempting to create associated asset](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SGxBQAW).

The last updated date on that case is 2019-06-27 (currently 7 1/2 months) and it's still in review. Depending on your patience, you may want to request an update on that case as well.